# Avoid lead conversion mapping on database.leadconversion

Tags: lead-conversion

I have a requirement where I don't want to map lead standard fields to account which comes by default on lead conversion.

Scenario:
We have built our app such a way that an account will be created  on click of custom convert button on lead. After account creation we want to call database.leadconvert() to mark the lead as converted(also to have the fields like covertedaccountid on lead and convertedleadid on account populated) which salesforce provides, when we do that the standard field which we don't intend to map from lead are being updated on account which we don't want. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks and your inputs are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not an after update trigger (or Process Builder) on Account to revert the mapped fields back to null or to some hidden values you stage on the Account record that your custom app instantiates?

Comment: @cropredy Wouldn't you want to use the values from trigger.old since the account already exists? Either that or use a before update trigger to prevent the new values from being inserted from the lead. Bottom line is that he needs to create a custom lead conversion to replace the standard one that's built into Salesforce.

Comment: @crmprogdev yes, that might work too.  It was my initial thought as well and then I went for a cautionary approach to improve traceability.